# Sort crontab -l in order by comment

Tags: python, bash, sorting, cron

How do I sort `crontab -l` in alphabetical order after the last hash mark on each line?

```
* * * * * curl -m 10 https://google.com # C comment
# * * * * * curl -m 10 https://google.com # A comment
* * * * * curl -m 10 https://google.com # D comment
* * * * * curl -m 10 https://google.com # E comment
* * * * * curl -m 10 https://google.com # Z comment
## * * * * * curl -m 10 https://google.com # B comment
```

Comment: Why?  `cron` certainly doesn't care.  Unless you're OCD, this seems completely silly.

Comment: Because I have several hundred cron jobs. I use python-crontab to programmatically create the job which puts them in no certain order. Sorting by comment is to group them by name for readability by others. This won't actually sort the cron, just the output list that I version control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk` to prepend each line with the last field, sort on this new 'first' field, then strip this 'first' field from the results:

```
$ crontab -l | awk -F'#' '{print $NF"#"$0}' | sort -t'#' -k1,1 | cut -d'#' -f2-
# * * * * * curl -m 10 https://google.com # A comment
## * * * * * curl -m 10 https://google.com # B comment
* * * * * curl -m 10 https://google.com # C comment
* * * * * curl -m 10 https://google.com # D comment
* * * * * curl -m 10 https://google.com # E comment
* * * * * curl -m 10 https://google.com # Z comment
```

**NOTES:**

- this will treat white space as a sortable character, eg, `#<2_spaces>D` will be sorted before `#<1_space>A`
- with a bit more coding the `sort|cut` functionality could be rolled into the `awk` code

Comment: A [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `gawk` to sort:

```
crontab -l | awk -F'#' '
  { comment[$NF]=$0}
  END {
    n=asorti (comment, sorted);
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) { 
      print comment[sorted[i]]
    }
  }'
```

Comment: while not an issue with the small sample provided by OP, this will filter out entries with a common/duplicate comment, keeping only the 'last' one seen by `awk`; one (kludge): `comment[$NF,NR]=$0` ... ?